# How to I handle UI async processes with a Bloc StreamSubscription?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, cubit, flutter-cubit

So I have a flutter app which uses Bloc pattern. I'm still kind of new with how Blocs works compared to Cubits. But I get the general idea (events vs functions).

**The problem** is with an async process in the login flow, I'm unable to make my View wait for the whole async process, which involves an extra API call (inside a `StreamSubscription.listen({//api call here})`) after the user is authenticated with firebase.

Classes:

- View: View containing a button triggering process
- LoginCubit: Corresponding cubit for View class
- AppBloc: General Bloc for the app
- AppEvent: No need to show to keep this short. It just has the event classes definitions

---

So, I have a button that triggers the authentication process:

```
class View extends StatefulWidget {
  const View({super.key});

  @override
  State<View> createState() => _ViewState();
}

class _ViewState extends State<View> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => LoginCubit(),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Click Me'),
        onPressed: () async {
          context.loaderOverlay.show();
          await context.read<LoginCubit>().loginWithEmailAndPassword(context);
          context.loaderOverlay.hide();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This View class has it's own Cubit (not bloc) to handle the onPressed callback of the `ElevatedButton`:

```
class LoginCubit extends Cubit<LogInState> {
  LoginCubit(this._authenticationRepository) : super(const LogInState());
  final AuthenticationRepository _authenticationRepository;

  Future<void> loginWithEmailAndPassword(BuildContext context) async {
    var emitNavigation = false;
    try {
       //After the following call is completed, _AppUserChanged Bloc event is triggered to set user 
       //info in AppState class

      await _authenticationRepository
          .logInWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: 'em@il.com', password: 'Password')
          
        // This does not waits for extra API call of the _userSubcription stream .listen
        emit(state.copyWith(
            loginStatus: FormzStatus.submissionSuccess,
            successMessage:
                '${LocaleKeys.successSignInMessage.tr()}${context.read<AppBloc>().state.userDocument.fullName}'));
      });
    } on LogInWithEmailAndPasswordFailure catch (error) {
      // ...
    } catch (_) {
     // ...
    }
  }

}
```

So as one of the comment mentions, the `emit` with the successful message does not waits for the `userDocument` model to be queried and mapped. I can tell because the message has NULL as fullname or just gives an error if I apply null check to it. The async process that creates the userDocument is defined as an event on the `.listen()` of the `StreamSubscription` defined in the AppBloc class:

```
class AppBloc extends Bloc<AppEvent, AppState> {
  AppBloc({required AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository})
      : _authenticationRepository = authenticationRepository,
        super(
          authenticationRepository.currentUser.isNotEmpty
              ? AppState.authenticated(
                  authenticationRepository.currentUser, null)
              : const AppState.unauthenticated(),
        ) {
    on<_AppUserChanged>(_onUserChanged);
    on<_AppUserDocumentChanged>(_onUserDocumentChanged); // Event definition
    on<AppLogoutRequested>(_onLogoutRequested);
    _userSubscription = _authenticationRepository.user.listen(
      (user) {
        add(_AppUserChanged(user));

        // -> userDocument creation event, needs the user id of the just authenticated user
        add(_AppUserDocumentChanged(user.id));
      },
    );
  }

  final AuthenticationRepository _authenticationRepository;
  late final StreamSubscription<FirebaseAuthUser> _userSubscription;

  void _onUserChanged(_AppUserChanged event, Emitter<AppState> emit) {
    emit(
      event.user.isNotEmpty
          ? AppState.authenticated(event.user, null)
          : const AppState.unauthenticated(),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onUserDocumentChanged(
      _AppUserDocumentChanged event, Emitter<AppState> emit) async {
    if (event.userId.isEmpty) {
      const AppState.unauthenticated();
    } else {
      try {
        // -> The aysnc flow works fine until it runs the following line, when this is
       // executed, the flow continues with the emit in the LoginCubit wihout waiting for the next two lines to be executued (which I need)

        final userInfo =
            await _authenticationRepository.getUserDocumentById(event.userId);

        emit(AppState.authenticated(state.user, userInfo));
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

  void _onLogoutRequested(AppLogoutRequested event, Emitter<AppState> emit) {
    unawaited(_authenticationRepository.logOut());
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _userSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

Just read the couple comments detailed in this. I also tried to implement this in single event, like using the `_onUserChanged` event for the whoel process but it did not work as well. Any idea of how to fix this or what am I doing wrong?

Here's the actual authentication authenticationRepository method:

```
 Future<void> logInWithEmailAndPassword({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      // this triggers bloc event _AppUserChanged
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
    } on firebase_auth.FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // ...
    } catch (_) {
      // ...
    }
  }
```

and the `user` stream getter:

```
  Stream<FirebaseAuthUser> get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().asyncMap((firebaseUser) {
      final user =
          firebaseUser == null ? FirebaseAuthUser.empty : firebaseUser.toUser;
      _cache.write(key: userCacheKey, value: user);
      return user;
    });
  }
```

**UPDATE**

@Boseong 's answer (ideal method) worked, but there's another problem. In the scenario of having an active session and rebuilding the app, I would need to redo the same async call in order to map `userDocument`.

Comment: Should the login cubit be awaiting the call to

    _authenticationRepository
          .logInWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: 'em@il.com', password: 'Password')

Comment: @JohnWeidner sorry, I removed it because I was trying out some things but it originally had it and it has the same error.

Comment: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ideal method: use repository to sync data

It's not recommended that use BuildContext in BLoC (or Cubit). Because BLoC is a Business Logic which is not related with render tree.

So, try use repository to sync data, or sync data in render(widget) tree.

```
await _authenticationRepository.logInWithEmailAndPassword(...);
final user = await _authenticationRepository.user.first;
final userDocument = await _authenticationRepository.getUserDocumentById(user.id);
final message = LocaleKeys.successSignInMessage.tr();
final fullName = userDocument.fullName;
emit(state.copyWith(
    loginStatus: FormzStatus.submissionSuccess,
    successMessage: '$message$fullName',
));
```

#### another method: wait until bloc state change

if you want to use BuildContext in LoginCubit, wait until AppState in AppBloc changed authenticated with UserDocument property.

sample code

```dart
await _authenticationRepository
    .logInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: 'em@il.com', password: 'password');
await context.read<AppBloc>.stream.firstWhere(
  (state) => state.userInfo != null,
);
final message = LocaleKeys.successSignInMessage.tr();
final fullName = context.read<AppBloc>().state.userDocument.fullName;
emit(state.copyWith(
    loginStatus: FormzStatus.submissionSuccess,
    successMessage: '$message$fullName',
));
```

Comment: Thanks your ideal method worked. I now realize that this solves the issue when log in process occurs, but how would you approach to the situation where you have an active session when application launches? I would have to redo the same  process,  but I can't since it was a `LoginCubit` flow. I guess you would have to still modify the initial events detailed in `AppBloc` or not? (will update post with this)

Comment: isn't enough to listen AppBloc state?